# How to capture a DOM click with Python / Django?

Tags: python, django, dom

I want to create a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game with Python. It will be just a 3x3 table.

The question is how to capture a click when user clicks on a specific cell?
Do I need to use JavaScript / jQuery for this ar can it be done with Python?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use JS to capture the click then JS should send a post request to Django with the position of the click.

Comment: 1. Write some HTML to define your 9 fields and give each field an ID.
2. when one of those IDs is clicked send an xhr/ajax request (you need javascript for this)
3. validate the input (filed which was clicked) with python and send a response to the frontend (html,js)